# Fast and free Wi-Fi spot in Gaborone

Tags: internet, wifi, botswana

Fast and reliable Wi-Fi can we a rare commodity in Botswana. Most hotels, guesthouses and residentials usually have rather slow internet connection (750 kbps- 1.5 Mbps).

I am looking for stable connection with fast internet, so I can update my mac.
I don't mind spending the day in a coffee shop, but keep in mind, Sierra update is about 4.6 GB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily comprehensive but perhaps 'a start', from [Service Wi-Fi Space](https://wifispc.com/botswana/south-east-district/gaborone.html) where there is also a map:

[image: TSE81624 example]

In a Comment OP has reported:

> Europa did have the best internet in town for a while, but something happened and now Macs can't connect. Mugg and Bean is a SA chain and they give you a voucher with one hour of very slow internet.

Bull & Bush is a pub/restaurant and [Nicleb01](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurant_Review-g293767-d1212052-Reviews-Bull_Bush_Pub-Gaborone_South_East_District.html#review_435652220) has recently confirmed *Free wifi is a bonus*. Linga Longa [is a creation of those who run Bull and Bush](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurant_Review-g293767-d3172640-Reviews-Linga_Longa-Gaborone_South_East_District.html).